# gtkmm MenuBar Not Visible or Not Properly Added to Grid

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I've recently started development on a C++ project using GTK+ and its C++ bindings (gtkmm). My project was originally going to be written in Vala, but I would rather have the more direct access to the machine that is available in C and C++. However, I'm having some trouble with my GTK menu bar. The relevant source code is at the following [link](http://pastie.org/2857904) (I used a pastebin because I didn't want to fill up too much space on this page).

When I performed the appending of widgets this same way in Vala, it worked fine. What am I missing (I have a feeling it is going to be painfully obvious)?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by doing the following:

```
MenuBar* mainMenuBar = Gtk::manage (new MenuBar ());
mainBox.pack_start (*mainMenuBar);
```